# Converting useState to a class component in Next Js latest

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

Got stuck in step 1, because we can’t use hooks in class components. My app is a class component.

So, I was wondering how can I create an equivalent to this in class component?

`const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(0) const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar)`

I never can convert this to class component. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into how [Class component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) works by itself, just invest 10 minutes, I'm sure if you have knowledge about the hooks, you will get used to it in no time.

Just to get you started here is the example you asked for;

```
 class YourClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sidebar: 0 // this is a good place to set Initial value
    };
  }

  showSidebar = () => { // This is a method of the class, similar to your arrow f
    this.setState({ sidebar: !this.state.sidebar });
  };

  render() {
   return // render your things here, similar to what you "return" in hooks
   // You can use your this.state.sidebar value here, similar to "sidebar"
  }
}
```